# x-axis symbols on Data scroll in Echarts not scrolling correctly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, echarts

I am making a simple bar graph using echarts js with symbols on x Axis. I am also trying to do datascroll for the xAxis, but when I am scrolling the symbol positions are not changing with the scroll. I go through the API doc of echarts but found nothing. 
I am trying this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3p2m3n4/)

```js
var advertLineChart = document.getElementById('advertLineChart');
var myAdvertLineChart = echarts.init(advertLineChart);

createAdvertLineChart();

function createAdvertLineChart() {


  var option = {
    title: {
      x: 'center',
      text: 'ECharts例子个数统计',
      subtext: 'Rainbow bar example',
      link: 'http://echarts.baidu.com/doc/example.html'
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item'
    },
    toolbox: {
      show: true,
      orient: 'vertical',
      y: 'center',
      itemSize: 12,
      feature: {
        mark: {
          show: true,
          title: {
            mark: 'Create line mark',
            markUndo: 'Undo line mark',
            markClear: 'Clear all line Marks'
          },
          lineStyle: {
            width: 2,
            color: '#1e90ff',
            type: 'dashed'
          }
        },
        dataZoom: {
          show: true,
          title: {
            dataZoom: 'Data Zoom',
            dataZoomReset: 'Data zoom reset'
          }
        },
        dataView: {
          show: true,
          title: 'Show Data',
          readOnly: false,
          lang: ['Data View', 'Close', 'Refresh']
        },
        magicType: {
          show: true,
          type: ['line', 'bar'],
          title: {
            line: 'Line View',
            bar: 'Bar View'
          }
        },
        restore: {
          show: true,
          title: 'Restore'
        },
        saveAsImage: {
          show: true,
          title: 'Save as Image',
          lang: ['Click Save']
        }
      }
    },
    dataZoom: {
      show: true,
      realtime: true,
      showDetail: true,
      //orient: 'vertical',   // 'horizontal'
      //x: 0,
      y: 36,
      //width: 400,
      height: 20,
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba(221,160,221,0.5)',
      //dataBackgroundColor: 'rgba(138,43,226,0.5)',
      //fillerColor: 'rgba(38,143,26,0.6)',
      //handleColor: 'rgba(128,43,16,0.8)',
      //xAxisIndex:[],
      //yAxisIndex:[],
      start: 40,
      end: 70,
      zoomLock: true
    },
    calculable: true,
    grid: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      y: 80,
      y2: 60
    },
    xAxis: [{
      type: 'category',
      show: false,
      data: ['Line', 'Bar', 'Scatter', 'K', 'Pie', 'Radar', 'Chord', 'Force', 'Map', 'Gauge', 'Funnel', 'Line1', 'Bar1', 'Scatter1', 'K1', 'Pie1', 'Radar1', 'Chord1', 'Force1', 'Map1', 'Gauge1', 'Funnel1', 'Funnel2', 'Line2', ]
    }],
    yAxis: [{
      type: 'value',
      show: false
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'ECharts例子个数统计',
      type: 'bar',
      itemStyle: {
        normal: {
          label: {
            show: true,
            position: 'top',
            formatter: '{b}\n{c}'
          }
        }
      },
      data: [12, 21, 10, 4, 12, 5, 6, 5, 25, 23, 7, 12, 21, 10, 4, 12, 5, 6, 5, 25, 23, 7, 20, 100],
      markPoint: {
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'item',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
          formatter: function(params) {
            return '<img src="' + params.data.symbol.replace('image://', '') + '"/>';
          }
        },

        data: [{
          xAxis: 0,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Line',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://localhost:8080/api/advert/image/21af6834-2b44-4217-9516-3b2add06114c.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 1,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Bar',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://localhost:8080/api/advert/image/5268c2b2-0b1f-4373-b235-7f71b6bb4290.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 2,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Scatter',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://localhost:8080/api/advert/image/69a7df86-0bf6-4cea-a6b6-881a4052ec20.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 3,
          y: 320,
          name: 'K',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/de874b8f-f8df-4905-9650-8efa8f19c015.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 4,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Pie',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/b83f4915-8587-4df5-bde6-308ec0f472b3.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 5,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Radar',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/db739705-c9e3-47bd-a3de-7e757ce0c434.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 6,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Chord',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/131201d2-9154-4391-89e7-73d83c12d33c.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 7,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Force',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/158dd833-a788-4e83-a7fd-ba42addaae31.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 8,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Map',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/b6933882-f367-419e-8f6e-df65ae74a859.png '
        }, {
          xAxis: 9,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Gauge',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/bae5221a-02e7-407a-8fa3-36bb8456dafa.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 10,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Funnel',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 11,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Line1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 12,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Bar1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 13,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Scatter1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 14,
          y: 320,
          name: 'K1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 15,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Pie1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 16,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Radar1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 17,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Chord1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 18,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Force1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 19,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Map1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 20,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Gauge1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://neoma-server.appspot.com/api/advert/image/03dc461c-20fc-49b7-8ef4-59649995fcb8.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 21,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Funnel1',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://localhost:8080/api/advert/image/69a7df86-0bf6-4cea-a6b6-881a4052ec20.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 22,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Funnel2',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://localhost:8080/api/advert/image/5268c2b2-0b1f-4373-b235-7f71b6bb4290.png'
        }, {
          xAxis: 23,
          y: 320,
          name: 'Line2',
          symbolSize: 16,
          symbol: 'http://localhost:8080/api/advert/image/21af6834-2b44-4217-9516-3b2add06114c.png'
        }, ]
      }
    }]
  };

  myAdvertLineChart.setOption(option);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/2.2.7/echarts-all.js"></script>
<div id="advertLineChart" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
```

How to scroll the images correctly when scrolling the slider? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the images you want to scroll?

Comment: @Ovilia -  these are the small thumbnails. I am taking the example from [link](http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/bar14.html#-en) , but with added slider.